# My datagrid doesn't update even though my other bindings do

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, observablecollection

I have an observableCollection containing objects of my class Player and I have a datagrid which is bound to that collection and which display the names of the players and their game score. I also have a label which is bound to the name contained in an object (also of class Player) named ActivePlayer so I can display which player's turn it is. When player 1 ends his turn, his turn's score is added to the total of his game score, then the reference contained in ActivePlayer is changed for the reference of the next player in the collection, the DataContext of my label and my datagrid are updated (at least they are supposed to be) and while the label changes, my datagrid doesn't and I don't understand why.

I tested displaying the player's game score in the label instead of his name to see if it was the points' data that wasn't updated, but when the turn came back to player 1, his updated score appeared so the collection and it's players are updated.

Here is my class Player code:

```
public class Player
{
    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Points = 0;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get => $"{Name} : "; }
    public string DisplayPts { get => $"{Points} pts"; }

     
    public void AddPts(int pts)
    {
        Points += pts;
    }
}
```

my XAML code for the datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDisplay" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="White"
                      FontFamily="Maiandra GD" FontSize="15" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                      CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                      CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None" Margin="5,15,5,0" 
                      RowHeight="35" Focusable="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="True">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayName}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayPts}" CellStyle="{StaticResource dgCellPoints}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Width="*" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
```

the initialization in the codebehind of my window:

```
ObservableCollection<Player> ListPlayers;

int Turn;

int TurnScore;

Player ActivePlayer;

public Game(List<Player> listP)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ListPlayers = new ObservableCollection<Player>(listeJ);
    Turn = -1;
    TurnScore = 0;
}

private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    NewTurn();

}
```

and here is my function for a new turn in the code-behind of my window:

```
private void NewTurn()
        {   
            Turn++;
            
            if (Turn == ListPlayers.Count) Turn = 0;

            ActivePlayer = ListPlayers[Turn];

            lbActivePlayer.DataContext = ActivePlayer.Name;
            dgDisplay.DataContext = ListPlayers;
}
```

What's really bothering me is that my datagrid does display the names and the "0 pts" for each when the game window loads so the binding did work at least the first time "NewTurn()" is called so why does it stop working after that? I tried specifying ListPlayers in my datagrid ItemSource like I saw on other exemples but it didn't work either. I tried binding my second column to Points instead of DisplayPoints but as I thought it had no effect, it just kept diplaying "0". For some reason I decided to change the initialization of Player' Points to 250, just to see if it would display 0 or 250 and it did show 250 so like I said the first DataContext binding does work on my datagrid but after that my datagrid stays the same no matter what points are added to the players' game score. Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Update:
As asked by mm8, my list of players is created in the previous window (let's call it the home window) where the players sets the number of players and enter their names. When they click on the "Start the game" button, the program retrieves all the names and creates the list, creating each Player with their names as it adds them to the list. It then pass the list to game window as it opens it.

Here is also the code calling the game window in the previous window:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Player> listP = new List<Player>();

            foreach(object child in stackPanelNewGame.Children)
            {
                if(child is CustomControlPlayer)
                    listP.Add(new Player((child as CustomControlPlayer).InputText));
            }

            Game g = new Game(listP);
            g.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect to see in the `DataGrid`? Where are you adding items to `ListPlayers`?

Comment: My first column display the name of the players, the second columns display their game score. As for creating the list, it is made in the window (let's call it the home window) that calls the game window. in the home window, they set the number of players (max 6) and they enter a name for each player. when the "Start the game" button is pressed, the program takes each name and create the list of player, creating the object Player at the same time. Once the list is created it passes it to the game window as it calls it.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Either set the itemssource of your datagrid and lose the itemssource = binding. Or implement inotifypropertychanged and use a more mvvm conventional approach. Set the datacontext of your window to a viewmodel instance, bind itemmssource to a property and set that,vraising propertychanged.

Comment: Also. Don't use ui as a data store.